# Terminating a process

Tags: c++, winapi, process

We have an application that has 3 processes as shown in the image below.

[image]

What I wanted to do is to terminate these processes. After reading a few tutorials, I was able to collate these codes. However, it's not working properly. The output is shown after the code.

```
   HANDLE hProcessSnap;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
    hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );
    pe32.dwSize = sizeof( PROCESSENTRY32 );

    std::string message = "";
    int processCounter = 0;

    while( Process32Next( hProcessSnap, &pe32 ) ) {
        char ch[260];
        char DefChar = ' ';
        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP,0,pe32.szExeFile,-1, ch,260,&DefChar, NULL);

        //A std:string  using the char* constructor.
        std::string process(ch);

        if( process == "bridge.exe" ) {
            std::wstring stemp = std::wstring(process.begin(), process.end());
            LPCWSTR sw = stemp.c_str();

            HWND windowHandle = FindWindowW( NULL, sw );
            DWORD* dwProcessId = new DWORD;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId( windowHandle, dwProcessId );
            message.append( process );

            message.append( "-" );
            std::ostringstream converter;
            converter << *dwProcessId;
            message.append( converter.str() );
            message.append( "-" );

            DWORD dwDesiredAccess = PROCESS_TERMINATE;
            BOOL  bInheritHandle  = FALSE;
            HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(dwDesiredAccess, bInheritHandle, *dwProcessId);

            if( hProcess == NULL ) {
                BOOL result = TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0);
                message.append( "NULL" );
            }
            message.append( "\n" );
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
        }
   }
```

This is the output:

```
bridge.exe-4597928-NULL
bridge.exe-4597568-NULL
bridge.exe-4587524-NULL
```

hProcess returns NULL. What did I miss? Thanks.

Comment: Call GetLastError() to find out why OpenProcess failed. You might want to check if FindWindowW() and GetWindowThreadProcessId() succeeds or fails too.

Comment: You are trying way too hard. To manage a group of processes as a single unit you might want to use [Job Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161.aspx) instead. That's what they were invented for.

Comment: Why aren't you checking for errors when you call Win32 API functions? How will you know that they succeeded without checking?